Who sees the Craft 4 License renewal popup screen/timer?
Does my customer see the new license pop up (with the countdown/refresh timer) in a craft 4.11 site?
I noticed that I get the popup as a "super" admin on the site, but I want to ensure they get it as well, as they are pay/renew direct with a craft ID account.
Their user account just has some basic CP entry editing permissions, is that enough for them to get a popup? I read somewhere that admins see it, wasn't too clear?!
Thanks for any clarification.

As long as you use a paid Craft CMS Edition (Craft PRO or Craft TEAM) or Plugin, anybody who accesses the backend will see the notice if the the Edition/Plugin has not been licensed yet.
You can solve that by downgrading to Craft Solo - and making them Admin. Or you go for the new, cheaper, Team Edition.
If your client paid the license via Craft ID, you might want to check the license and see if it is correctly assigned to the domain.
